# System.Random giving duplicates in runtime

Tags: c#

Normally, when I call this method of mine

```
    public static int Randomize(int min, int max)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.Next(min, max);
    }
```

I get a completely different number everytime.

But as soon as I start to use this method during runtime (60fps / 16 updates per ms), this method gives me almost only duplicates.

I can understand that `Random` could have not enough time to shuffle a random number, but how could I achieve a reliable random-method for ingame-runtime use?

Comment: Don't create a new Random every time.

Comment: Coding questions not specific to gamedev should be asked on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random doesn't need "time" to shuffle a random number.  The algorithm generates a new number each time it's called, based on the current state (which changed during each call).  Like any mathematical function, given input `A` will always produce the same output `B`.  If you keep resetting `A` to the same value (by reinstantiating `Random` every time you use it) then of course you will keep getting the exact same "random" output `B`.

A very simple way to picture it is that it does something like:

```
class Random:
  int state = 0x718AE8F2 // or whatever default number
  int Next(int min, int max):
    int num = (max - min) * (this.state / INT_MAX) + min
    this.state = AdvanceState(this.state)
    return num
```

The actual algorithm in `AdvanceState` being used (could be one of many) does a lot of complicated bit manipulation/math when changing the state in order to make it seem random to a casual observer.

Creating a new Random() of course means you're always starting out with the same default seed/state and hence you always get the same number.

The advantage is that you can intentionally reset the state of `Random` (seeding it) if desired to get the same sequence of "random" output, which is handy for testing or sharing a randomly generated level with just a single number (the seed).

Comment: Specifically with C#'s random class, the default seed is the system time in milliseconds.